# bin/ksh cat statement not assigning to variable

Tags: shell, sqlplus, ksh, cat

I'm trying to setup a variable as the login information for an sqlplus statement:

```
#!/bin/ksh    

DB_AUTH=`cat $BASEDIR/src/env/.$1`@$2
    export DB_AUTH
    echo DB_AUTH=$DB_AUTH

    sqlplus -s $DB_AUTH <<ENDOFSQL...(sql statement)
```

I've verified that $BASEDIR, $1, and $2 are all passing to the script correctly, but when I run the script, DB_AUTH returns nothing and the script crashes/doesn't connect to Oracle.

The cat $BASEDIR/src/env/.$1 statement also works when I enter it as a command line.  Just doesn't work inside my script.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You should always give a working example, like an example of the parameters and the content of the file you are trying to "cat".

Comment: As a comment on a deleted answer you write that the problem is solved. Please remove this question or post your solution and accept it. That way other people won't try to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that someone had posted a file named "cat" on the server by mistake.  We deleted the file and it all ran fine.  Thanks for your answers.  And Andre, yes, I'll give more info next time.  Thank you.